Как удалить postgres полностью
Я установил pgadmin4, но неправильно ввел свою почту. В итоге я захотел переустановить приложение, чтобы начать регистрацию заново, но web приложение осталось, а повторная установка не предлагает регистрацию. Я использую ubuntu. Вот что я вводил.
 sudo apt install pgadmin4
 2003  # Setup the repository
 2004  #
 2005  # Install the public key for the repository (if not done previously):
 2006  curl -fsS https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/packages-pgadmin-org.gpg
 2007  # Create the repository configuration file:
 2008  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/packages-pgadmin-org.gpg] https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
 2009  #
 2010  # Install pgAdmin
 2011  #
 2012  # Install for both desktop and web modes:
 2013  sudo apt install pgadmin4
 2014  # Install for desktop mode only:
 2015  sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop
 2016  # Install for web mode only: 
 2017  sudo apt install pgadmin4-web 
 2018  # Configure the webserver, if you installed pgadmin4-web:
 2019  sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
 2020  sudo su - postgres
 2021  psql
 2022  sudo pg_isready 
 2023  sudo service postgresql restart
 2024  sudo -u postgres psql
 2025  createdb mydb
 2026  ps -ef | grep postgres
 2027  pg_lsclusters
 2028  $ sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
 2029  sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
 2030  $ sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
 2031  sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
 2032  sudo systemctl status postgresql.service
 2033  sudo -i -u postgres
 2034  sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql postgresql-*
 2035  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
 2036  wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
 2037  sudo apt-get update
 2038  sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
 2039  sudo systemctl status postgresql
 2040  sudo -u postgres psql
 2041  sudo apt-get --purge remove pgadmin3
 2042  sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*
 2043  sudo rm -r /etc/postgresql/
 2044  sudo rm -r /etc/postgresql-common/
 2045  sudo rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/
 2046  sudo userdel -r postgres
 2047  sudo groupdel postgres
 2048  sudo apt remove pgadmin4
 2049  history


Но http://127.0.0.1/pgadmin4/browser/ все еще работает и я ничего не могу сделать.
Пожалуйста подскажите как мне это исправить.
Скорее всего я сделал что-то очень глупое, но я только учусь работать с linux и postgres это курс в моем вузе, поэтому для меня это пока черный ящик.

Вопрос должен звучать не как "Как удалить pgadmin полностью", а "Как удалить postgres полностью". Удаление вебформы вам ни как не поможет. Это просто UI

Хорошо, но все же как это сделать?

В /etc/ есть чё-нить про пгадмин? В смысле работает? Ты его через systemctl stop не остановил что ли?

посмотри здесь https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191762/how-to-uninstall-pgadmin4-on-ubuntu-16-04
